# Cant create folder inside the folder in Ubuntu using php

Tags: php, directory, creation

Can any one say how we can create folder using php.

I tried to create folder inside /var/www/php but it fails . Why is it so?

My code is like this

```
<?php
$path=getcwd.'/images';
mkdir($path,777);
?>
```

What is the error in this script.

Comment: "What is the error in this script." - you should tell us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use the wrong function
change `getcwd` to `getcwd()` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at the folder permissions. Using ls, check the group of the folder in which you want to create a new folder. Also verify that writing is allowed to the groups. Finally, the server executing your php script must be member of this group.